# Any function to fix or shorter the winding path?

Tags: php

Sometimes we may include a file which path is generated by script,
and there maybe have some winding part in the path,

for example:

```
include("\deep1\deep2\deep3\..\..\path\to\file");
```

Here you can see some unused winding path,
we know the shorter(better) path to include file would be

```
include("\deep1\path\to\file");
```

and the middle part of path,
such as `"\deep2\deep3\..\.."`
just go and back to the original point

the question is,
is there any function can detect and remove the middle unused path?

I think this is not very important, but maybe can have some better performance :p

thank you~

Comment: When the OS resolves the path for inclusion, there shouldn't be an issue. Performance impact is negligible here even if the path stays as is.

Comment: There is no such thing as middle unused path, path is path. If you generate it wrong, fix generation.

Comment: You can surely make a function that does this, but adding that your project would just be a waste of time. You can rather try it as a programming exercise.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: @IłyaBursov Thank you, realpath() works fine for me, question solved!! ^^b